# Factory Girl: Specify Trait for Parent

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I would like a factory to inherit from another factory with a specific trait. How can I specify a parent factory with a specific trait as the parent? I'm looking for something along the lines of how you can declare an association with a specific trait, like this:

```
  factory :mom do
    trait :smart do
    end
  end

  factory :kiddo, parent: [:mom, :smart] do
    ... #does not work
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this should work:

```
factory :mom do
    trait :smart do
    end
  end

factory :kiddo, parent: :mom, traits: [:smart] do
end
```

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the heads up.